What should our About contain?
As suggested on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/, we should define our own site.
Some guidelines are already provided on the about

What to ask

Specific issues with Italian language
Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

What not to ask

Anything not directly related to Italian language
Questions that are primarily opinion-based
Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer


but I think we should gather here other guidelines whenever they are discussed and we come to a community agreement.

We don't have a FAQ anymore...

The FAQ was simply renamed 'Help'. That doesn't invalidate the question. This community still has to consider what their site is going to be about, and what is on and off topic. It's an important function of meta and a big part of why we have a private beta.

The ELU meta site has a great topic on proper references and sources. It'd be useful to have something like this in FAQ for Italian.

Questions about translation requests
As per Are questions about translation requests on topic?, questions asking for a translation of a text are considered off-topic, unless they show effort on the asker's side and they include attempted translations.
Questions about translation of Italian expressions to other languages are also considered off-topic, and they should be migrated to the appropriate language site, whenever applicable.

Also: on topic translations should be other language > Ita, since translation requires more expertise in the target language. I'd put the other ones as off topic (and to be migrated to the respective sites if they appear).

I agree. I'll edit my post

Questions about etymology
As per Are etymology questions on topic?, questions about etymology are considered on topic.

Questions about dialects
As per Are questions about dialects on topic?, questions about dialects are on topic only when they directly relate to the Italian language.
Questions with little or no relationship with the Italian language are considered off-topic.
